# postname giving URL was not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, debian, apache2

I have an issue by getting permalink to work on debian8.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and permission `666`.

But then I change my permalink to `postname` instead of plain and I get:

> requested URL was not found on this server

on all of my URLs except the start page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses Apache's "mod_rewrite" to serve pages and posts using permalinks, and it sounds like that module is not enabled on your server. To enable it, type `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, and then restart Apache. After that, permalinks should work.

You can also set any file permissions that you changed back to what they were originally.

**Edit:**
In your Apache config, you might also need to change the AllowOverride setting. The default on Ubuntu does not allow all .htaccess directives to work, so it's likely the same on Debian. You can use `AllowOverride All` or choose specific options instead. `FileInfo` is the one you will need for mod_rewrite. Apache's docs (2.4) for AllowOverride are here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Interesting, that's usually all that's necessary. Do you have the WordPress files installed directly in the site's root? (i.e., is the login page at domain.com/wp-login.php?)  If the files are in a subdirectory, as described at https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory under "Method II", it might be that the .htaccess or index.html doesn't exist in both the root and subdirectory.

Comment: AllowOverride All was the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the below command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```